# android studio. i ask about the use of on item click listener function. how it work?

Tags: android

```
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] hotel = {"one room", "double room", "suit", "vip"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, hotel);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),adapterView.getItemIdAtPosition(i)+"is Checked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),adapter.getItem(i),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Could anyone explain to me how on item clickListener work?  what `View view , int i , long I` mean on `(onclick item listener`?. A new Adapter view class or object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OnItemClickListener** is a `Listener` which keep listening for the events. When you click any item in the `ListView` then this interface will fired and it'll call the `onItemClick` callback(abstract method). So just override this method and put your code which needs to run when the item is clicked. In your case, you're just showing the item id with **Toast**.

**onItemClick** : It is a `Callback` method in Android. This can be invoked when an item in this `ListView` has been clicked.

This method accepts four parameters `adapterView, view, i, l`

> **AdapterView(adapterView):** The AdapterView where the click happened. This might be a ListView, GridView etc. These classes are derived from the `AdapterView` class.
>
> **View(view):** The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the adapter). The `View` parameter passed in the `onItemClick()` method when you click the item in the ListView.
>
> **int(i):** The position of the view in the adapter. By this way, you can get the item. Position starts from 0 to n.
>
> **long(l):** The row id of the item that was clicked.

Please see this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html). Hope this helps you...

Comment: Do you understand ? If my answer helps you then accept it.  @KareemIbraheem

Comment: this is my first time i put a question her . i accept it . if any other procedure ?  tell me to do it.

Comment: To accept the answer you've to click tick mark. I hope now you understand about onItemClickListener